# "If $|\sin x + \cos x |=|\sin x|+|\cos x| (\sin x, \cos x \neq 0)$, in which quadrant does $x$ lie?"

Tags: trigonometry

"If $|\sin x + \cos x |=|\sin x|+|\cos x| (\sin x, \cos x \neq 0)$, in which quadrant does $x$ lie?"

What I did:
For this equality, signs of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ must be same.
Therefore $\sin x\cos x>0$
Multiplying and dividing by $2$,
$\sin 2x>0$
$$0<2x<\pi$$ $$0<x<\frac{π}{2}$$

That gives the value of $x$ in the first quadrant.

But the sign of $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are also the same in the third quadrant, so where did I go wrong in my solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You could also try giving $x$ values from each of the quadrants and seeing for which quadrant the equality holds

Comment: @pranav Yeah but I wanna figure out what's wrong with the solution I tried.

Comment: $\sin 2x > 0 \implies 2k \pi < 2x < 2k \pi + \pi \implies k \pi < x < k \pi + (1/2) \pi$. For $k = 0$ is 1st quadrant, and $k = 1$ is 3rd quadrant. To keep in mind: $\sin$ is a periodic function, with period $2 \pi$

Comment: @junkquill yeah that's what I missed out on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta = 2x$.

If $0 < x < 2\pi$, then $0 < 2x < 4\pi$, so you need to check for angles between $0$ and $4\pi$ in which $\sin\theta > 0$.

$$\sin\theta > 0 \implies 0 < \theta < \pi~\vee~2\pi < \theta < 3\pi$$

Replace $\theta$ by $2x$.  The inequality

$$0 < \theta < \pi \implies 0 < 2x < \pi \implies 0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

while the inequality

$$2\pi < \theta < 3\pi \implies 2\pi < 2x < 3\pi \implies \pi < x < \frac{3\pi}{2}$$

so we obtain angles in the first and third quadrants as solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin2x>0\iff \color{green}{2k\pi}<2x<\pi\color{green}{+2k\pi}\iff \color{green}{k\pi}<x<\frac\pi2\color{green}{+k\pi}.$$

Comment: Yep, got it! Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

We know that
$|a+b|=|a|+|b|$ iff $a$ and $b$ share the same sign. Now if $(a,b)$ is a point in the coordinate system satisfying that property is must be in quadrant $1$ or $3$.